# Regex to extracting GRANT Statements from string

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to create a regex for extracting GRANT Statement. I

Sample string is given below:

```
USE MarketWorkFlowDb
GO
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE   [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp] 
    @pType VARCHAR (50), --function/role/region
    @pFieldId INT, --id which is deleted
    @pRequestTypeId INT=0
AS
BEGIN
IF (@pFieldId >0)

BEGIN
    IF @pType='Function'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE LkpCategoryTb
        SET IsDeleted=1, LastUpdatedBy='Admin', LastUpdatedDate=GETDATE()
        WHERE CategoryId=@pFieldId AND RequestTypeId = @pRequestTypeId

    END 

    ELSE IF @pType='Role'
    BEGIN

        UPDATE LkpRoleTb
        SET IsDeleted=1,  LastUpdatedBy='Admin', LastUpdatedDate=GETDATE()
        WHERE RoleId=@pFieldId AND RequestTypeId = @pRequestTypeId
    END

    ELSE IF @pType='Region'
    BEGIN
        UPDATE LkpRegionTb
        SET IsDeleted=1, LastUpdatedBy='Admin', LastUpdatedDate=GETDATE()
        WHERE RegionId=@pFieldId AND RequestTypeId = @pRequestTypeId
        -------------------------Updates Approver Manager Table--------------------------------
        UPDATE RegionalPeopleTb 
        SET IsDeleted =1,  LastUpdatedBy='Admin', LastUpdatedDate =GETDATE() where RegionId= @pFieldId and RequestTypeId= @pRequestTypeId
    END 

END
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE 


ON [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp] TO User_grp WITH GRANT OPTION

GRANT EXECUTE 
ON [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp] TO User_grp 
GO
```

I am using `".*(grant\s+.*?to\s+\[?[A-Za-z_]+\]?)\s.*"` Regex to extract the Grant statement but it only gives me first match.

C# Code i am using for this

```
 input = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\MarketWorkFlowDB3.0\DatabaseObjects\StoredProcedures\DeleteLkpDataSp.sql");

            input = Regex.Replace(input, "\r\n", @"\s");

            Match match = Regex.Match(input, @".*(grant\s+.*?to\s+\[?[A-Za-z_]+\]?)\s.*",
             RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

How i can get all the grant statements.

Comment: That actually depends not on your pattern but on the regex engine you are using.  Please add the code you use to run the regex.  Thanks!

Comment: What are the boundaries for the match?  Try `var res = Regex.Matches(input, @"(?mis)^(grant\s+.*?to\s+\[?[A-Za-z_]+]?)")`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `Regex.Matches` to get all matches
2. You should use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline` instead of replacing `\r\n` with literal `\s`

I don't know what is a good regex for your grant statement, but that depends on the full syntax of a grant statement

**EDIT**

Your regular expression is not conducive for multiple matching. You should use code like below

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(grant\s+.*?to\s+\[?[A-Za-z_]+\]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Thsi will still match statements like

> GRANT OPTION
>
> GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[DeleteLkpDataSp] TO User_grp